# Is there a way to parse a relative date using Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, date, formatting, momentjs

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is a very usefull JavaScript library which provides many functions to manipulate date formatting.

In order to create a Moment object, it is possible to [parse a string](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) simply `moment("1995-12-25");` or by providing format `moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");`.

Another feature allows us to use [relative dates](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) : `moment("1995-12-25").fromNow() // 19 years ago`.

However, I can not find a way to parse such a relative date. When I try `moment("19 years ago")` it just returns `Invalid date`, and it does not exist any token to properly format the date.

Is there an easy way to do this? Or is it a missing feature that should be suggested on Github?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way of doing this is `moment().sub(19, 'years');`

What you are asking imply a [Natural language processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) which is whole computer science field.

Comment: So this is not really "parsing" a date, too bad. I will suggest this feature on Github, then.
However, I am not sure to fully understand your second remark. I really do not see why such a parser imply using a complex technique like NLP. Relative dates are always formatted in the same way : `3 years and 6 hours ago` or `In 1,4 months` for example. It is not complicated to recognize keywords and then compute the date, Moment.js parser already do this.

Comment: @Delgan - It has been requested multiple times and rejected as out of scope for the core library by the moment.js authors.  Nobody has yet to step up to produce a plugin for it either.  Feel free to step up if you are interested! :)   The main complexities are with regard to supporting the feature in multiple locales, but there are other subtle issues as well.

Answer (score 11):

Just found [chrono](https://github.com/wanasit/chrono) wile looking to see if NLP had already been implemented in momentjs.  It looks like it handles parsing NLP to a date, which can be used to create a momentjs date.

> Simply pass a string to function chrono.parseDate or chrono.parse.
>
> ```
> > var chrono = require('chrono-node')
>
> > chrono.parseDate('An appointment on Sep 12-13') 
> Fri Sep 12 2014 12:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
> ```

And a quick example showing how that would work

Code

```
const moment = require('moment')
const chrono = require('chrono-node')

let now = moment()
console.log(now)
let yrsAgo = chrono.parseDate("19 years ago")
console.log(yrsAgo)
let yrsAgoMoment = moment(yrsAgo)
console.log(yrsAgoMoment)
```

Output

```
$node test.js
moment("2017-06-30T08:29:20.938")
1998-06-30T17:00:00.000Z
moment("1998-06-30T12:00:00.000")
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the plugin relative.time.parser.  The original intent was to parse relative time from graphite [from/until](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/render_api.html#from-until), so I was only going for the 'reverse' in time.

I will take a look at adding the 'NLP' use cases as well.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: and this has what to do with momentjs?

Comment: It is a moment.js plugin.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, i thought you were talking about a graphite plugin.

Comment: No worries.  If that's the worst thing that happens to us today, it will be all right.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin which very recently appeared on github, which is a plugin to moment to allow this sort of parsing:  https://github.com/cmaurer/relative.time.parser

I have not personally tried it, but I will shortly (found both it *and* this question while searching for the same thing).

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work with the example I provided, it is a plugin used to parse `+19years` for example. But thanks for sharing.

Comment: My mistake, I figured there was some flexibility in the relative format.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily using moment plus little logic. Here it is working perfectly

```
function parseSincUntilDate(dateStr, now = new Date()) {
  // inputs: 20 minutes ago, 7 hours from now, now, '', or UTC string
  if (moment(dateStr).isValid()) return moment(dateStr).toDate();
  const tokens = dateStr.split(' ');
  if (dateStr.includes('ago')) {
    return moment(now).subtract(tokens[0], tokens[1]).toDate();
  } else if (dateStr.includes('from now')) {
    return moment(now).add(tokens[0], tokens[1]).toDate();
  } else if (dateStr === 'now' || dateStr === '') {
    return new Date(now);
  }
  return moment(dateStr).toDate();
}
// to change relative date, pass it in second parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
moment.fn.parse = function(_relative, _format){
    var _modulo = moment.normalizeUnits(_format);
    return this.add(_relative, _modulo);
}

moment("30/08/2015", "DD/MM/YYYY").parse(-20, "years").format('DD/MM/YYYY'); // 30/08/1995
moment("30/08/2015", "DD/MM/YYYY").parse(-2, "week").format('DD/MM/YYYY'); // 16/08/2015
moment("30/08/2015", "DD/MM/YYYY").parse(-2, "d").format('DD/MM/YYYY'); // 28/08/2015
```

Answer (score -2):

As of Moment.js 1.0.0 (October 2011) to current:

```
moment().add(7, 'days');
moment().subtract(1, 'seconds');
```

Works with years, quarters, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds.

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/